# Not able to search by name using Map quest COMMUNITY EDITION (Licensed Data) API

Tags: mapquest

I am not able to search by name using Map quest COMMUNITY EDITION (Licensed Data) API.

This api allowed me to search only for "T" value which are  given in the Table below under the given url.

Alternate Display Type Mappings url is

http://www.mapquestapi.com/search/ds-ntpois.html#MQA.NTPois

For example i want to search Imaging But i did not find any way to find name which are not in given list
Pls Reply

Answer (score 0):

The [MapQuest Search API](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/dev-services/search-ws) hosted data search offers over 2 million POIs in 50+ categories.  Unfortunately, Imaging is not one of the categories that is available for searching.  The categories [on the list](http://www.mapquestapi.com/search/ds-ntpois.html#MQA.NTPoisCat) are the categories that are available for searching.

If you have any questions, let me know!  Also, there is a [Search API forum](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/forums/-/message_boards?_19_mbCategoryId=208316) on the [MapQuest Developer Network](http://developer.mapquest.com), so feel free to take a look!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want to search a place by specifying a place name. For example I want to search all the places starting with "Good"   in particular area like  "Good health institute"  etc.

How can I do it in mapquest API. Please help.

Comment: Unfortunately, the Search API Web service is optimized for spatial searches, like radius and polygon searches, and is not optimized for string searches.  You can filter your POI results by category (the T values), but at this point a string search such as 'name LIKE good' is not supported.  Sorry for the inconvenience!